# Excel: Links from PNG plan to other spreadsheets

Tags: excel, hyperlink, spreadsheet

I inserted a floor plan (PNG) into the first spreadsheet in Excel (via Insert/Images) over n*m cells, on which 10 rooms can be seen.
For each room I created another spreadsheet with tabular information about the room.
Is it somehow possible to click on a room in the floor plan and go directly to the corresponding spreadsheet for the room?
So I should somehow be able to put a spreadsheet link in front of or behind each room.
Can someone help?
Thanks in advance

I tried to get access to the cells behind each room, but without success.
Also I draw a rectangle over one room, but I do not know, how I could add a spreadsheet link to it.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you are going to set hyperlink to sheet `BedRoom`.

- step1: Right-click on the rectangle shape (or select it) to bring up the context (pop-up) menu.
- step2: Click "Hyperlink" from the context menu. This will open the `Insert Hyperlink` dialog.

In the Insert Hyperlink dialog box:

- In the "Link to" section on the left, select "Place in This Document"
- In the "Or select a place in this document" section, you will see a list of all the sheets in your workbook. Click and select "BedRoom".
- In the "Type the cell reference" box, enter "A1" (or any cell reference you want to link to on "BedRoom").
- Click "OK" to create the hyperlink.

You should now have a hyperlink attached to the rectangle, linking to `BedRoom!A1`.

---

Please refers to Microsoft document.

> [Work with links in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/work-with-links-in-excel-7fc80d8d-68f9-482f-ab01-584c44d72b3e?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

Comment: But when shifting the floor plan in the spreadsheet, the rectangle shapes do not shift with the plan. Is it possible to fix the rectangle shapes to the floor plan?